# ListView (Inside Linear Layout) along with TextViews and EditText was not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Here is my layout which contains TextViews and EditText and ImageButtons
ListView is added as a last item in layout so search results would be displayed in listview format..
When the list items get larger enough so that user wants to scrool , the  list view ain't responding to scrolling..
NOTE : I'm Deleting some margin and padding attributes for cut-shorting the xml file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
        android:text="Welcome to MeetUps"
        android:textSize="32sp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Find Your Mentor , Be A Mentor ."
        android:textColor="#cccccc"
        android:textSize="18sp"
       />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchRegd"
        android:background="@drawable/et_search_background"
        android:hint="Search By Regd No."
        android:textColorHint="#3c3c3c"
     />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchSurname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:hint="Surname"
        android:textColorHint="#3c3c3c"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchFirstName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="36dp"

        android:background="@drawable/et_search_background"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:textColorHint="#3c3c3c"

        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchLastName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:textColorHint="#3c3c3c"
       />
</LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/action_search_name"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewMeetups"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

        </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the list to be scrollable.. when list gets large

[image]

Comment: Your image isn't viewable. Something seems wrong with your markup. Also, you might want to set the width/height for all other controls. I noticed some are missing it. Not sure if that could affect things. Also, look in your logcat to see if there are any warnings/errors while running the app.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't allowing me to upload an image..I deleted only margin and padding attributes for views so it would be more readable..

Comment: set ListView height to match_parent or some fix value. you should not use wrap_content for width or height of listview. this is bad for performance because all item will be loaded at the same time and it's also break scrolling.